# Primefaces calendar validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to validate a calendar as an input text with popup button
the input text has been validating correctly. However the selection of a date from the popup button cannot be validated 
My xhtml code is:

```
<p:calendar value="#{indexBean.searchCriteria.date}" 
            id="date" showOn="button"
            mindate="#{indexBean.searchCriteria.mindate}" maxdate="#{indexBean.searchCriteria.maxdate}"
            label="Date" converterMessage="The Date must be of the form DD/MM/YYYY and be a valid date"
            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" validator="#{indexBean.validateDate}" widgetVar="dateCalendar"
            timeOnly="false">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    <p:ajax update=":messages" event="change" />
</p:calendar>
```

what should i do to apply the validation on the popup button as well???

Comment: what do you mean by validation on pop up button?

Comment: please follow the link
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarBasic.jsf;jsessionid=1ui9rj6c9nk3hapjezpo2oj4o
athe popup Button is the third type of the Primefaces Basic Calendar

Answer (score 1):

Using ajax, you should be able to key into the `dateSelect` event of the calendar, and perform a standard, ajax driven validation. According to the docs, the popup mode can also trigger ajax events on `blur` and `keyup`. The `change` you've specified is only good for the input text bit of the calendar

Comment: Thanks kolossus
I decided to go with the jQuery datePicker instead
Cheers